# How can I resize Navigation Bar? (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to increase the height of `NavigationBar`, but it's hard to find solution for current version of `xCode` (and `iOS`) Is there no way to customize a size of navigation bar without making my own custom header view? It will be grateful for any help. Thank you.

Comment: Might be worth including either `swiftui` or `uikit` tag

Comment: i added new tag, thanks :)